# How much more memory can I put in this new Mac mini?

Tags: mac, upgrade, memory

http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/Apple-Mac-Mini-1-66GHz-Core-Duo-1GB-80GB-/110578889116?pt=UK_Computing_Apple_Desktops_CV#ht_1853wt_1137

So I was thinking of buying the cheapest Mac to build iPhone apps. And I want to add more RAM. What's the maximum capacity of RAM I can put on this beast?

Comment: might be better posted on superuser

Answer (score 1):

Supports up to 2GB. See here: http://support.apple.com/kb/SP34

Answer (score 0):

According to [memory.com](http://www.memoryc.com/apple/17413_macmini166ghzmemory.html) this computer has 2 DDR2 RAM slots, with maximal RAM of 2 GB when using 2 sticks of 1GB.

I have not managed to find any source that says that your model can accept 2GB RAM sticks for a total of 4GB, so probably 2GB is the real limit.

Your computer has probably has 2 sticks of 512MB, so you will need to buy a 2x1GB kit and replace both of them.